# Retrieve row id from table displayed in webpage

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a MySQL table that is displayed in the webpage and every row has a submit button. When the submit button for a particular row is clicked, the first element i.e. row id should be retrieved. Should I use arrays to store the data or can I obtain the row id from the table I've echoed on screen. Here's the code:

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td align='center' name='bus_id'>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[7] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row[7] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><form name='f1' method='post' action='schedule_list.php'>
                <input type='submit' name='book' value='Book'></form></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
}
 echo "</table";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a a button with type submit to submit the ID as follows (and still display a meaningful button title

```
echo "<td><form name='f1' method='post' action='schedule_list.php'>
                <button type='submit' name='book' value='".$row[0]."'>Book</button></form></td>";
```

Comment: but then how do I get that id value when it is clicked??

Comment: $_POST['book'] will be the the id value;

Comment: never mind..I got it. It was a pretty silly question.xD..thank you for your help